# change contents without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a page. Its a key shop website.
I want to make that when the customer clicks on the icon, for example `windows7`, it removes the other products beside it, and write its description and payment button.
I already succeeded in not allowing the page to refresh, and only view the content.
But the problem is the tab; I want to change it in the end of the page, and whenever I click on the icon for `windows7` it opens to me the page I want, but from the top.
I'am using the following code:

```
 <script>
     $("div.haha").tabs("img.one > div", {effect: 'ajax'});
 </script>
```

i just want it to change content and not to start from top

```
<div id="haha">
    <a href="product1.html"><img class="one" src="imgs/product1.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="two" src="imgs/product2.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="three" src="imgs/product 3.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="four" src="imgs/product4.png"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: you should make your jQuery call like this: $('#haha') which select by ID property of an element.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you looking for code to actually target the div and change the div to new content?  Or was your current code just not changing the div?  If its just not changing the div, it is because of what developer82 said in comment and zavg said in answer.  I would recommend using ` $('#haha')` compared to `$("div#haha")` though as it is a cleaner code in my opinion.

Comment: Hello i edited the code but it is still changing the page to top of it not in the same place

Answer (score 3):

Actually to access `div` with "haha" `id` you should use

`$("div#haha")`

selector.

Comment: Hello i edited the code but it is still changing the page to top of it not in the same place

Comment: do you have code to prevent the link from doing default?  A link by default will change the page.  You need to make sure you have `return false;` inside your function and possibly even `e.preventDefault();` depending on how your script is set up.  Also, I'm pretty sure to accomplish this, you'll need to set up the code in a javascript function so that all the code works together.

Comment: and yes i just want it to change contents and stay at the place it was not return to up i am newbie in javascript

Comment: I have posted an answer.  You'll see lines like `e.preventDefault();` and `return false;` which prevent the browser from taking normal actions on links.  I just used demo text and content so you could see how it works.  Normally, in this code the url would change and it would setup so the back button would change; however, I took those out because from what I can gather, you don't need those features and it makes it easier with them not in there.

Answer (score 1):

I am changing the code, because I had this code on hand and it works pretty well from what I've seen and appears to fit all your needs.

Javascript:  (tested with jquery 1.9.1)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

  $("a[rel='haha']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    /*
    if uncomment the above line, html5 nonsupported browers won't change the url but will display the ajax content;
    if commented, html5 nonsupported browers will reload the page to the specified link.
    */

    //get the link location that was clicked
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

    //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'haha'
    $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=haha',success: function(data){
      $('#haha').html(data);
    }});

    //stop refreshing to the page given in
    return false;

  });

});

</script>
```

html example:

```
This is the code outside the div.  This shouldnt be effected.

<br /><br />
Here are the links outside the div to show you how it works.  IMG 2 will refresh page and change url because rel="haha" is missing from the url<br />
<a href="page2.php" rel="haha">IMG 1</a>
<a href="page2.php">IMG2 - NO REL</a> 
    <a href="../index.php">IMG3</a>
    <a href="http://www.kygar.com/code/haha.php">RESET</a>


<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="haha" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">
    <a href="../index.php" rel="haha">IMG1</a>
    <a href="../services.php" rel="haha">IMG2</a>
    <a href="http://www.gmail.com">IMG3 - NO REL</a>
</div>
```

Just know, any link you want to load into the div needs a rel="haha" (which can be changed to whatever you want to call it).  If you want the page to load completely (like changing pages), just leave out the rel="haha" from the url.

Demo of how the code works: http://kygar.com/code/haha.php

Comment: thanks mate,can anybody tell me how to do this slide show please?  http://i.imgur.com/qYOwNPu.png

Comment: This is a completely different question.  You might want to go ahead and finish out this question (accept an annswer, or say it didn't work) and then ask your new question as a new stack overflow question.